# Express the following Matrix A as a product of elementary matrices.

Tags: matrices

been struggling with this and was hoping for tips/solution.

“Express the following Matrix A as a product of elementary matrices if possible”

$$
 A =  \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1 & -1 \\
 0 & 2 & 1  \\
 -1 & 0 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
$$

It’s fairly simple I know but just can’t get a hold off it and starting to get frustrated, mainly struggling with row reduced echelon form and therefore cannot get forward with it.

Comment: Which matrices do you call "elementary" ?

Answer (score 1):

Row reduced echelon form can be turned into successive **left** multiplications by elementary matrices; for example $E_1$ for the first step (creating a zero in the lower left entry) defined in this way:

$$\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\1&0&1\end{pmatrix}}_{E_1}\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}&R_1&\\&R_2&\\&R_3&\end{pmatrix}}_A=\begin{pmatrix}&R_1&\\&R_2&\\&R_1+R_3&\end{pmatrix}=  \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1 & -1 \\
 0 & 2 & 1  \\
 0 & 1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$$

($R_k$ = $k$th row).

Then chain with a second multiplication by a certain $E_2$ (that I leave you find) in such a way that

$$T=\underbrace{E_2E_1}_EA=\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1 & -1 \\
 0 & 2 & 1  \\
 0 & 0 & 3/2
\end{pmatrix}$$ has an upper triangular form.

Now do the same thing but by acting this time on columns by **right** multiplying by convenient elementary matrices. Here is the first step:

$$\underbrace{\left(C_1 \ \ C_2 \ \ C_3 \right)}_T \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & -\tfrac12  \\
 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}}_{F_1}=\left(C_1 \ \ C_2 \ \ (C_3-\tfrac12 C_2) \right)=\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1 & -\tfrac32 \\
 0 & 2 & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & 3/2
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then you have to find $F_2$ and $F_3$ such that
by chaining them, you get a diagonal matrix:

$$T\underbrace{F_1F_2F_3}_F=D \ \iff \ \ EAF=D$$

Yielding :

$$A=E^{-1}DF^{-1}$$

knowing that a diagonal matrix can be called an elementary matrix.

Recall: the inverse of an elementary matrix is itself an elementary matrix.

Comment: When doing Gaussian Elimination we can also do column operations provided that the matrix is upper-triangular? I was taught using elementary row operations only, so this is interesting!

Comment: @dansidorkin : indeed, this bilateral "attack" because it is symmetric, has virtues of his own, giving in particular the celebrated LU decomposition.

Comment: No comment, a day later ? This site is based on dialog, don't forget it...

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. What are the conditions on LU decomposition? You mentioned 'because it is symmetric' in your response. Perhaps to avoid confusion, is lower/upper triangular form defined in terms of square matrices only?

Comment: I'm going to answer my own response ... the triangular matrix is a special case of square matrices .... and the condition on LU decomposition has to be that the matrix is invertible ... Do correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: Hi! Thank you for detailed and interesting response Jean Marie!